# How to check if two values exist in a list using linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq statement that looks like this:

```
if(items.Any(x => x.CustomerID == 4))
{

}
```

however, I want to find an object in my list of items that not only contains the customerID of 4 but also a designID of 6.

I know I can do this:

```
if(items.Any(x => x.CustomerID == 4) && items.Any(x => x.DesignID == 6))
{

}
```

but this may not work since I need to find the **same** object that has both these values (this would check individually if these exist). Is there a way to combine these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine two conditions like `x.CustomerID == 4 && x.DesignID == 6`

```
if(items.Any(x => x.CustomerID == 4 && x.DesignID == 6))
```